# linear vs non-linear kernel SVM

Tags: svm, linear-model, nonlinear, rbf-kernel

The dataSet contains 213 examples of 7 classes . Each example are 25000 features. I want to learn model with SVM (test scenario used are 10-fold cross validation). I am a beginner in machine learning, i want to know what type of kernel i should use in the case of my data: linear or no-linear (as RBF kernel). Also, I want some tips to choose the value of parameter C. Thanks!

Comment: Cross-validate. That said, 7 classes from 213 elements is a bit of a tall order...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By elements you mean samples/examples right?

If your dataset consists of 213 samples of 25000 features each you have a **much** more serious problem to solve than the selection of your SVM hyper-parameters.

In short 213 samples provide are **very few** for the dimensionality of your problem. In high dimensional spaces you typically need lots of data have a sufficient representation of the space (and this is just **one** of the [problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality) associated with high-dimensional data). The **main** issue you have to deal with is **feature selection**, in order to reduce the number of features.

Now to answer your question:
If I were to choose, I'd take a **linear kernel** in such a problem. The last thing you need is to project the data to an *even higher* dimensional space.